# Projection is not being respected when rendering a UIElement into a WriteableBitmap

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, uielement, writeablebitmap

I am using Silverlight 4 and am having trouble correctly generating bitmaps from `UIElements` that have a projection applied to them.

In my specific case I am using the `WriteableBitmap` class to capture a bitmap of an `Image` control which has a `Matrix3DProjection` applied to it. This projection represents a non-affine transform which is used to transform the Image into an arbitrary quadrilateral. The resulting bitmap is then saved for later use.

Unfortunately, projections seem to be ignored when `WriteableBitmap` captures a `UIElement`. This also seems to be the case for any RenderTransform that may be attached, although this can be addressed by using an overload on the `WriteableBitmap` constructor that accepts a `Transform`. No such consideration seems to have been made for projections.

The following contrived code example illustrates the point. It transforms a `Button` rather than an `Image` component, but the effect is the same.

The XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="button" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="50" Click="button_Click">Render me</Button>
    <Image x:Name="image" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Height="200" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        button.Projection = new Matrix3DProjection()
        {
            ProjectionMatrix = new Matrix3D()
            {
                M11 = 0.825, M12 = -0.513, M13 = 0, M14 = 0.001,
                M21 = 0.023, M22 = 0.986, M23 = 0, M24 = -0.002,
                M31 = 0, M32 = 0, M33 = 1, M34 = 0,
                OffsetX = 0, OffsetY = 0, OffsetZ = 0, M44 = 1
            }
        }; 
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Render the button as a bitmap and display
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(button, null);
        image.Source = bitmap;
    }
}
```

When run, you will find that an image of the button is rendered into the `Image` component, but without the distortion that is obvious on the original button itself.

I've tried playing around with both the constructor and `Render` method on `WriteableBitmap`, with all of their various overloads with no success. I have also tried nesting the source `UIElement` within other elements and applying the projection at varying levels of the tree to see if `WriteableBitmap` would render a projection correctly if it was as part of a larger composite structure. No luck there either.

Hopefully I am just missing something simple here, but I suspect that this just may not be possible in the current version of Silverlight.

If this is indeed a dead end, then a viable alternative to me would be to be able to directly apply the matrix transformation to a bitmap, bypassing the whole `UIElement.Projection` piece of silverlight altogether. However, I don't really know where to start when it comes to taking a source bitmap, feeding it's pixels through such a transformation, and collecting the resultant output. The fact that the transformation is non-affine suggests to me that there will be some level of interpolation involved, and that the math requirements for such a solution are probably significant.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `LayoutTransformer` from Silverlight Control Toolkit (System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit assembly)

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <toolkit:LayoutTransformer x:Name="lt" >
            <Button x:Name="button" Click="Button_Click">Click me</Button>
        </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>

        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100">
            <Image x:Name="image"  Width="100" Height="100" />
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button.Projection = new Matrix3DProjection() { ProjectionMatrix = new Matrix3D() { M11 = 0.825, M12 = -0.513, M13 = 0, M14 = 0.001, M21 = 0.023, M22 = 0.986, M23 = 0, M24 = -0.002, M31 = 0, M32 = 0, M33 = 1, M34 = 0, OffsetX = 0, OffsetY = 0, OffsetZ = 0, M44 = 1 } };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(lt, null); 
        image.Source = bitmap; 
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm - thank you very much! I'm still not clear on exactly what makes this work, so I'm going to go through the LayoutTransformer code and see if I can figure it out. I'll post my findings back here when I'm done.

Comment: Hmmm - looks like I was not as thorough with my initial experiments of nesting the source element in other controls as I thought. It turns out that applying the projection to the child, but rendering to a WriteableBitmap from the parent works as expected. LayoutTransformer works but is not required. A simple parent Border will do the same trick. I'll leave this answer as the accepted one, but will add another with the relevant details. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem turned out to be simple. Just make the source `UIElement` the child of another, and then apply the projection to the child element, but use the parent element when rendering to a `WriteableBitmap`. Modified code example below:

The XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="border" Width="200" Height="200" Grid.Column="0">
        <Button x:Name="button" Width="120" Height="50" Click="button_Click">Render me</Button>
    </Border>
    <Image x:Name="image" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Height="200"/>
</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    button.Projection = new Matrix3DProjection()
    {
        ProjectionMatrix = new Matrix3D()
        {
            M11 = 0.825, M12 = -0.513, M13 = 0, M14 = 0.001,
            M21 = 0.023, M22 = 0.986, M23 = 0, M24 = -0.002,
            M31 = 0, M32 = 0, M33 = 1, M34 = 0,
            OffsetX = 0, OffsetY = 0, OffsetZ = 0, M44 = 1
        }
    }; 
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Render the button as a bitmap and display
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(border, null);  
    image.Source = bitmap;
}
```

Thanks to @foson for getting me to take a harder look at this.